# Nodejs: Colorize code snippet (syntax highlighting)

Tags: node.js, logging, colors, console, colorize

I've been searching the web for `npm` module that could colorize the `console.log` output in my console. See the example bellow:

```
console.log('function(){ "my colorized javascript" }'.colorize);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/colors

Comment: @Jordonias I'm looking for something like `console-highlight`. A module that can parse a string as a code snippet.

Comment: Ah so syntax highlighting.

Comment: Yes, syntax highlighting (title updated).

Answer (score 0):

I found [console-highlight](https://github.com/dtao/console-highlight) which looks promising.